# how can I get the top element of model-view stack in openGL?

Tags: opengl

I want to save the top element, pop it, push something new to the stack, and finally push the saved element to stack. I suppose glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrix) fills matrix with the whole model-view stack not just the top element, right?

Comment: It's about time to use the programmable pipeline where you have full control of your matrices...

Answer (score 1):

> glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrix) fills matrix with the whole model-view stack not just the top element, right?

You think wrong. It gets the topmost element and glLoadMatrix sets the topmost element.